# Can't create Word.Application

Tags: object, vbscript, ms-word, ole

this is pretty strange. I'm trying to run a pretty simple vbs code from a terminal server and I have amongst others, this line:

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

Strangely enough, this worked yesterday. But now, all that happens is that wscript.exe just seems to hang. I even tried to put a messagebox before the creation of the Word object and after. And the message box after is never shown. On my local computer however, this works fine. And yes, the terminalserver does have Word installed.

What could be causing this?

Edit: Is it better to do this routine from the templates instead? I mean, that would eliminate the need to create the Word object since it's already created once the templates is opened.

Comment: When you execute the script, is a new process called WINWORD.EXE created in the Windows task manager? Do you find any error message in the Windows event log? When you open Word manually, does it open a blank document or does open a dialog (such as the dialog for activation of Office).

Comment: Well, no, no WINWORD.EXE is created, but I can run winword.exe just fine from the command line. That's why I thought this was a little weird. It just kinda hangs on wscript.exe. Also, the last message box which is supposed to appear after WINWORD.EXE is initialized is never shown. Meaning it's hanging somehow. On error resume next is not set btw :) I have managed to do this using a Word template macro though.

Answer (score 1):

i'd kill winword.exe from your script, and then run the objword command. That could help.